# Find the names of these countries

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus

From the pictures below, can you find the names of the corresponding countries?

**1)**[image]

**2)**[image]

**3)**
[image]

**4)**

[image]

**5)**

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1

> **CUBA** (cube+ah)

2

> **DENMARK** (den+mark)

3

> **FINLAND** (fin+land)

4

> **TAIWAN** (tie+won)

5

> **PAKISTAN** (pack+is+stan)

Comment: Yep, its correct! (+1)